# Mat-checkbox checked property determined by modal response

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I have an array of users and in HTML I used ***ngFor** to generate a checkbox for each element.
I also have an **@Input assignedAccountIds[]** which represents the default selected users.

The checkbox element is the following one:

```
<mat-checkbox
   color="primary"
   [disabled]="disableCurrentAccountCheckbox && account.id === currentAccountId"
   [checked]="isAccountSelected(account)"
   (change)="onSelectAccount($event, account)"
>
```

**isAccountSelected** method verify if a user exists in the selected items array to know if I need to check it or not, and here is the implementation:

```
isAccountSelected(account: ClientAccount): boolean {
    return (this.assignedAccountIds || []).includes(account.id);
}
```

On the **change** output, the method implementation is the following one:

```
onSelectAccount(event: MatCheckboxChange, account: ClientAccount): void {
    if (
      !event.checked &&
      this.currentAccountId &&
      account.id === this.currentAccountId
    ) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
        data: {
          message: `You will not be able to see this inspection if you unassign yourself!`,
          buttonColor: 'primary',
          buttonLabel: 'Unassign',
        },
        position: {
          right: '10px',
          bottom: '10px',
        },
        maxWidth: '580px',
      });

      dialogRef
        .afterClosed()
        .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
        .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
    } else {
      this.selectionChange.emit({ id: account.id, checked: event.checked });
    }
  }
```

So, what I'm actually trying to do is to display a confirmation modal when you want to unselect yourself from the list. And only after you select **Yes** or **No** from the modal, the checkbox will remain checked or will be unchecked.

Comment: What problem are you having? What doesn't work?

Comment: I can't find a method to wait for a modal response. The problem is that the checkbox is unchecking too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatCheckbox` does not provide a built-in way to "intercept" a check/uncheck action. You can only listen to the change event after it happens. However, you can use an ordinary click event to do the intercepting:

Checkbox

```
<mat-checkbox #cb (click)="confirmAssign($event)">Assigned</mat-checkbox>
```

Dialog actions

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Unassign</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('cb', {static: true}) cb: MatCheckbox;

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

confirmAssign(event) {

  // only intercept if currently checked
  if (this.cb.checked) {

    // stop the click from unchecking the checkbox
    event.preventDefault();

    // ask for confirmation
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent).afterClosed().subscribe(confirmed => {
      if (confirmed) {
        // uncheck the checkbox
        setTimeout(() => this.cb.checked = false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v15, the best way I've found to do this is to [provide a 'noop' MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS](https://v15.material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#click-action-config) to override the default click behavior:

#### Component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-checkbox-component',
    templateUrl: './app-checkbox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-checkbox.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { clickAction: 'noop' } as MatCheckboxDefaultOptions },
    ],
})
export class InlineHardCopyDeliveredEventComponent {
    isCheckboxChecked = false;

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openModal(): void {
        this.dialog
            .open()
            .afterClosed()
            .subscribe((result) => {
                this.isCheckboxChecked = result;
            });
    }
}
```

#### Template

```html
<mat-checkbox
    (click)="openModal()"
    [checked]="isCheckboxChecked"
></mat-checkbox>
```